# How to extract and recognize the vehicle plate number with matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr

I want to develop a matlab program that can extract and recognize the plate number of vehicle with template matching method.
Here is my code:

```
function letters = PengenalanPlatMobil(citra)
%load NewTemplates
%global NewTemplates
citra=imresize(citra,[400 NaN]); % Resizing the image keeping aspect ratio same.
citra_bw=rgb2gray(citra); % Converting the RGB (color) image to gray (intensity).
citra_filt=medfilt2(citra_bw,[3 3]); % Median filtering to remove noise.
se=strel('disk',1);
citra_dilasi=imdilate(citra_filt,se); % Dilating the gray image with the structural element.
citra_eroding=imerode(citra_filt,se); % Eroding the gray image with structural element.
citra_edge_enhacement=imsubtract(citra_dilasi,citra_eroding); % Morphological Gradient for edges enhancement.
imshow(citra_edge_enhacement);
citra_edge_enhacement_double=mat2gray(double(citra_edge_enhacement)); % Converting the class to double.
citra_double_konv=conv2(citra_edge_enhacement_double,[1 1;1 1]); % Convolution of the double image f
citra_intens=imadjust(citra_double_konv,[0.5 0.7],[0 1],0.1); % Intensity scaling between the range 0 to 1.
citra_logic=logical(citra_intens); % Conversion of the class from double to binary.
% Eliminating the possible horizontal lines from the output image of regiongrow
% that could be edges of license plate.
citra_line_delete=imsubtract(citra_logic, (imerode(citra_logic,strel('line',50,0))));
% Filling all the regions of the image.
citra_fill=imfill(citra_line_delete,'holes');
% Thinning the image to ensure character isolation.
citra_thinning_eroding=imerode((bwmorph(citra_fill,'thin',1)),(strel('line',3,90)));

%Selecting all the regions that are of pixel area more than 100.
citra_final=bwareaopen(citra_thinning_eroding,125);
[labelled jml] = bwlabel(citra_final);
% Uncomment to make compitable with the previous versions of MATLAB®
% Two properties 'BoundingBox' and binary 'Image' corresponding to these
% Bounding boxes are acquired.
Iprops=regionprops(labelled,'BoundingBox','Image');

%%% OCR STEP
[letter{1:jml}]=deal([]);
[gambar{1:jml}]=deal([]);
for ii=1:jml
    gambar= Iprops(ii).Image;
    letter{ii}=readLetter(gambar);
    % imshow(gambar);
    %
end

end
```

but the number recognized is always wrong and too much is detected or sometimes too little.
How to fix it?

Here is the [images](http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r649/farhat1s/DSC_0512_zpsa99acbea.jpg) and [this one](http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r649/farhat1s/1_zpsaa2585c2.jpg)

Comment: This is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926768/how-to-perform-automatic-number-plate-extraction-from-an-image/17935167#17935167, although you made the changes suggested in my answer to your previous post. My suggestion would be to isolate the license plate first from the rest of the image and then apply your code.

Comment: @Try Hard : i have made the isolated plate and do that same code, but the segmentation result is wrong..How to fix it..Any suggestion

Comment: In what sense is it wrong? It performs very well for me!

Comment: in the amount of the character extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the loop following character detection to

```
[gambar{1:jml}]=deal([]);

for ii=1:jml
    gambar{ii}= Iprops(ii).Image;
    %letter{ii}=readLetter(gambar);
    imshow(gambar{ii});
end
```

I think what you want to do at this point is either

(1) pick the roi in advance before applying character extraction and ocr.

or

(2) apply ocr to all of the characters from the entire image and then use proximity rules or other rules to identify the license plate number.

**Edit:**

If you run the following loop after character extraction you can get an idea what I mean by "proximity":

```
[xn yn]=size(citra); % <-- citra is the original image matrix
figure, hold on 
[gambar{1:jml}]=deal([]);
for ii=1:jml
    gambar{ii}= double(Iprops(ii).Image)*255;
    bb=Iprops(ii).BoundingBox;
    image([bb(1) bb(1)+bb(3)],[yn-bb(2) yn-bb(2)-bb(4)],gambar{ii});
end
```

Here is the image after edge detection:

[image: edges]

and after character extraction (after running the loop above):

[image: extracted]

Comment: What is "yn" variable mean?

Comment: I missed that: it is the size in the y dimension of the image.

Comment: From the character extraction, how  we can matching it with the template and know the exact value of the character?
because the extraction's character shape is too thick.

Comment: Do you mean ocr did not work for some characters because they were too thick? I'll look into it but I suggest you post another question asking this specifically. Ideally post one of the characters extracted from the license plate, and explain why your attempt to perform ocr on it did not work.

Comment: By the way, do you mean one specific character is too thick? For instance I can see that the B is too thick, but the "4" and "J" characters look ok.

Comment: For another image (http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r649/farhat1s/7_zps14dfdc9a.jpg), the extraacted character is also too thick. and there are some variable that merged as 1 variable..

Comment: How about Horizontal smearing for extract the variable. i have read it in internet but there are no one example code for it..

Comment: I looked at the other image you posted, and if you keep all of the parameters constant you do find that the character extraction is not good. But you can change the paramaters, for instance in the intensity scaling step with imadjust, or in the following imerode steps, and improve the result somewhat.

Comment: How about do localization of vehicle plates?

Comment: @FarhatMann Policy on the site is to post questions , not to seek a complete answer to your graduate thesis problem. Thus you should format your questions as reasonably sized and concrete problems, especially since the people on this site (mostly) operate for free and do not have infinite time to devote to your question. To encourage other people to help you, you should also be ready to click on the checkmark next to an answer if it does a reasonable job, and it is also polite to click on the up tick when people post nice answers, even if they are not the best. I address your question above.

Comment: @FarhatMann Two rules you can apply to find the license plate are: (1) using the **physical** size of the image, find rectangles of expected size for a license plate, and (2) identify the size and location of the symbols in elements extracted from the image, compare that to (a) the expected size of symbols in a license plate (b) look at the relative size of different symbols and (c) see if there are symbols clustered together (nearby) in the image (d) see if the symbols make any sense (e) check the relative position of the symbols and see if that makes sense. Lots to keep you busy...

Answer (score 4):

For number plate extraction you have to follow this algorithm(I used this in my project)

```
1. Find Histogram variation horizontally(by using imhist)
2. Find the part of histogram where you get maximum variation and get x1 and x2 value.
3. crop that image horizontally by using value of x1 and x2.
4. Repeat same process for vertical cropping.
```

Explanation:

In order to remove unnecessary information from the image, it requires only edges of the image to work. For detection of the edges, we make use of a built-in MATLAB function. **But first we convert the original image to grayscale image**.

This grayscale image is converted to binary image by determining a threshold for different intensities in the image. After binarization only, edge detection algorithm can be used. Here we have used ‘ROBERTS’. After extensive testing, it seemed our application the best. Then to determine the region of license plate we have done horizontal and vertical edge processing. First the horizontal histogram is calculated by traversing each column of an image. The algorithm starts traversing with the second pixel from the top of each column of image matrix. The difference between second and first pixel is calculated. If the difference exceeds certain threshold, it is added to total sum of differences. It traverses until the end of the column and the total sum of differences between neighbouring pixels are calculated. At the end, a matrix of the column-wise sum is created. The same process is carried out for vertical histogram. In this case, instead of columns, rows are processed.

[image: Horizontal and Vertical Histogram]

After calculating horizontal and vertical histogram we have calculated a threshold value which is 0.434 times of maximum horizontal histogram value. Our next step for extraction is cropping the area of interest i.e. number plate area. For cropping we first crop original image horizontally and then vertically. In horizontal cropping we process image matrix column wise and compare its horizontal histogram value with the predefined threshold value. If certain value in horizontal histogram is more than threshold we mark it as our starting point for cropping and continue until threshold value we find-less than that is our end point. In this process we get many areas which have value more than threshold so we store all starting and end point in a matrix and compare width of each area, width is calculated difference of starting and end point. After that we find set of that staring and end point which map largest width. Then we crop image horizontally by using that starting and end point. This new horizontally cropped image is processed for vertical cropping. In vertical cropping we use same threshold comparison method but only difference is that this time we process image matrix row wise and compare threshold value with vertical histogram values. Again we get different sets of vertical start and end point again we find that set which map largest height and crop image by using that vertical start and end point. After vertical and horizontal cropping we get exact area of number plate from original image in RGB format.

[image: Number Plate Extraction]

**For Recognition use template matching with correlation(using corr2() in matlab)**

Comment: nice, have you shared your code somewhere like on mathworks or github ?